# Using variable in parsing JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function like this:

```
function appendTable2(dinput,id) {
    return function(index, val) {
        $('#matrix_datatable').find(id)
            .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
                .append(val.value[0].dinput + '</td>')
            );
    };
}
```

And it's called like:

```
$.each(mainData.locations.source_values, appendTable2('address1','#mAddress'));
```

The problem is that this appends `undefined` to my table because of how this line works: `.append(val.value[0].dinput + '</td>')`

It's looking for an attribute in the object called `dinput` instead of the value of `dinput`. What's the proper syntax to use here?

Comment: append does not work like building a string

Comment: @epascarello I know that, but what will work here?

Comment: If `val.value[0].dinput` is an object and you want to get a property called "myproperty" do `val.value[0].dinput.myproperty`

Comment: [dinput] ......

Comment: make it one line...

Comment: .append('<td class="tableCells">' + val.value[0].dinput + '</td>')

Comment: @Jonasw That's what I needed. Tried everything, but that apparently!

Comment: @jonmrich js basics: .dinput is equal to ["dinput"]...

Comment: @t.niese look 5 comments above :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append is not like string concatenation. When you append the first element it is done, no adding anything else to it.

So either you build the string

```
.append('<td class="tableCells">' + val.value[0][dinput] + '</td>')
```

or set the text/html to the td

```
.append( $('<td class="tableCells"></td>').text(val.value[0][dinput]) )
```

Comment: Still [dinput] ...

Comment: `val.value[0][dinput]`... ;)